What is the word for a baseless or specious argument? Especially one that is immediately tossed out in court
I'm having trouble remembering this common word.  And it's not "trivial", or "empty", but means that.  I thought it started with an "s", but I didn't think the word was "specious".
Kinda like if an argument is laughed out of court.

Maybe it's "frivolous".  I can delete this question if the moderators want that.

I was going to suggest "spurious" but won't since you are willing to delete the question.

Neither 'specious' nor 'spurious' means immediately seen to be ludicrous. Some synonym of preposterous (this will be a hypernym)? Farcical?

yeah, i think i'm gonna delete the question.  I was trying for a half hour, to remember this word and Google and the synonyms dictionaries were not helping me out.  Sorry to waste everyone's time.

@EdwinAshworth it was like "immediately seen to be empty"  Like a non-argument presented to be an argument.  I'm not sure but now I think "frivolous" was the word I was trying to remember.

gonna delete in 10 minutes.  just in case someone else wants to pipe in.

Perhaps it is vexatious. But if you delete a question so soon it seems you don't really care about a good answer. Bye bye. Nobody will care about your ultimatum, but they might be interested by the question.

@WeatherVane , I don't mind a good answer.  I was just very frustrated because for over a half hour I just couldn't remember a common word that was a synonym to specious or baseless.  I know the word wasn't vexatious since I hadn't known that word before.  I'm pretty sure the word I was groping for is frivolous.

Please give it 24 hours, at least. Don't waste our time by deleting before an answer was posted, just because you have your word.

@WeatherVane , I did not make an ultimatum.  I just thought that my question was not worth keeping.  If you do, I will not delete it.  So now I am committing to not deleting the question.  If the mods think the question is worthless, they can delete it.

It's usually a community decision, unless the question is objectionable. And there may be a previous question that already answers it.

If it means 'trivial', there is some obvious research you can do.

@robertbristow-johnson Please do not remove this question. It has some merit as evidenced by the up votes (which you will lose if you delete it  )

@PeterJennings I have, 3 comments up, changed my position on deleting the question.  I am committed to not deleting it.  Originally, I thought the question was sorta unworthy of this SE.

It's more of a "duplicate" than others that were deleted. It's a hit-n-miss game IDC for. But I like unsubstantiated because it has 2 S-letters and lack of substance in a sense.

The argument is so unfounded that it's not worth a picayune.

"dismissed with prejudice"

Not really an answer to the question as asked, but I wonder if you’re thinking of the concept of prima facie.

I think Google's AI distilled these two summaries from Wikipedia.
In legal terms,...

A case is considered frivolous if it has no reasonable chance of succeeding.


A case is considered vexatious if it would cause hardship on the other party to defend against an unnecessary and unsuccessful claim.


So you can see them together, here's what the actual Wikipedia page says...

A "frivolous" claim or complaint is one that has no serious purpose or value. Often a frivolous claim is one about a matter that is so trivial, meritless on its face, or without substance that investigation would be disproportionate in terms of time and cost. The implication is that the claim has not been brought in good faith because it clearly has no reasonable prospect of success and/or is not significant enough to warrant its mention.


A "vexatious" claim or complaint is one being pressed specifically to cause harassment, annoyance, frustration, worry, or even bring financial cost (such as the engagement of a defence lawyer) to their defendant or respondent.


Can you put in a link to "the actual Wikipedia page"?

There is only one link in the ext, and it is to the Wikipedia page. I can't provide a link to the summary on the Google home page, because that's my Google homepage. Google always customized your version of its home page (to make sure you get relevant ads and "sponsored results", rather than for your benefit, I assume). I've used Google Bard (now Gemini) quite a bit, and for all I know I get that "distillation" where others don't.

...maybe I should have mentioned it in the answer itself, but one interesting point is the Wikipedia article is primarily concerned with use the composite "quasi-legal" term, not the distinction between the two. A bit like the lawyers use of the composite term aiding and abetting, what we have here is introduced by Wikipedia as... In law, frivolous or vexatious is a term used to challenge a complaint or a legal proceeding. Not really one or the other - the composite label is all they bother with. (It's an open-and-shut case, except lawyers don't use that form of words! :)

Maybe "nugatory".
Wiktionary nugatory
3.(law) Having no force, inoperative, ineffectual.

This is going directly into my everyday parlance.

They could be said to be making a spurious claim, especially if the one making the claim knows it to without merit.

Definition: Deceptively suggesting an erroneous origin; fake. Of
doubtful or low quality.

Definition quoted from https://www.lsd.law

If it really is an s-word you might be thinking of sophism or sophistry.



Your Honor, we respectfully submit a meritorious objection to the opposing party's claim, stating that these assertions are superfluous and do not add any substantial evidence to the case at hand.


Synonyms



Synonyms




Surplus, Redundant, Unneeded, Not required


Excess, Extra, Spare, To spare, Remaining


Unused, Left over, Useless, Unproductive


Undue, In excess, Surplus to requirements


Expendable, Disposable, Dispensable, Unwanted


Waste, Unnecessary, Needless, Inessential


Pointless, Uncalled for, Unwarranted, Unjustified, Gratuitous




Antonyms



Antonyms




Necessary, Essential




Origin



Origin                                                                 >




Late Middle English: From Latin superfluus, from super- ‘over’ + fluere ‘to flow’.






The term "superfluous" originates from the Latin superfluus, which translates to "overflowing" or "excessive". This Latin term combines super- (meaning "above" or "beyond") and fluere (meaning "to flow."). Over time, its meaning has evolved in English to denote something that is unnecessary or excessive.

For those interested in a more detailed exploration of the term's etymology and its implications, valuable resources are available from Lancaster University and the London School of Economics. These sources delve into the historical context and contemporary usage of "superfluous" across various fields, including law and literature. Specifically, the Encyclopedia of Shakespeare's Language provides insights into its usage in literary contexts, while the article Law and the Production of Superfluity offers an in-depth analysis of its implications in legal discourse. You can find more information through these links:

Encyclopedia of Shakespeare's Language

Law and the Production of Superfluity


Note: For those interested in the themes of justice and human dignity in King Lear, you may find valuable insights in the analysis of Lear's reflections on the human experience. These discussions highlight how his struggles resonate deeply with contemporary issues. For more detailed exploration, check out resources like the Royal Shakespeare Company and Stanford Global Shakespeare Encyclopedia.
William Shakespeare uses the term "superfluous" in "King Lear", particularly in Act 1, Scene 1, where Lear reflects on the burdens of kingship and the excesses of familial ties. This moment highlights the redundancy in relationships, emphasizing how such superfluities weigh heavily on human existence. In Act 2, Scene 4, Lear further laments the unnecessary nature of societal constructs, exploring the theme of superfluity in the context of power and responsibility:

"O reason not the need! Our basest beggars
Are in the poorest thing superfluous.
Allow not nature more than nature needs,
Man's life is cheap as beast's".

Here, Lear asserts that even the most destitute individuals possess something that is "superfluous", suggesting that human existence is burdened with unnecessary complications and that life's true value is often obscured by societal expectations.
This passage captures Lear's descent into madness and his growing awareness of the harsh truths about humanity and existence.

